# Port require, dokku digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, dokku

I create a droplet with a dokku image and deploy a rails app. Everything  works "fine", with the exception that I need specify the port to access the app, (e.g. 209.107.150.99:66445 or example.com:66445).

When I ssh the app and go to /home/dokku/my-app/nginx.conf I got this:

```
server {
 listen      [::]:22445;
 listen      22445;

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/<my-app>-access.log;
 error_log   /var/log/nginx/<my-app>-error.log;

 location    / {

   gzip on;
   gzip_min_length  1100;
   gzip_buffers  4 32k;
   gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component$
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level  6;

  proxy_pass  http://<my-app>-5000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
      gzip on;
  gzip_min_length  1100;
  gzip_buffers  4 32k;
  gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component$
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level  6;

  proxy_pass  http://<my-app>-5000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
}
 include /home/dokku/<my-app>/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
```

In this file if I change the 'listen' to 80 nothing happens, and when I restart or rebuild the app it changes back to 66445.

I don't know what to do, can't find to much information in google related to this. maybe I am missing something when I deploy? I followed this [guide](http://donpottinger.net/blog/2014/11/17/bye-bye-heroku-hello-dokku.html), except the plugins part.

**EDIT:**

There are four logs files in /var/log/nginx/.

access.log:

```
<my-ip> - - [06/Jul/2016:11:29:30 -0400] "POST /<my-ip> - - [06/Jul/2016:11:29:25 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3231 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
<my-ip> - - [06/Jul/2016:11:29:26 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3231 "http://<app-ip>/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
<my-ip> - - [06/Jul/2016:11:29:30 -0400] "POST /setup HTTP/1.1" 200 27 "http://<app-ip>/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
```

myApp-access.log:

```
<my-ip> - - [06/Jul/2016:13:12:44 -0400] "GET /payments/count_new_orders?_=1467823083139 HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "http://<app-ip>:<port>$/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
```

and the error.log and myApp-error.log are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum port number you can use is `65535`. The reason for that is in most(all?) tcp stack implementations port is unsigned 16-bit integer.

Change your listen config to use lower ports and it should work:

```
listen      [::]:65445;
listen      65445;
```

Comment: I change it in the example to a random number, is not the real port number that appears in the file but I'm going to change so people don't confuse, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a static port for your application setting an env variable

```
$ dokku config:set app_name DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=1234
```

then every time you deploy your application, you  have the same ip:port combination if you don't have a domain

you can go to ip:1234 and access to the app always and the port will be always the one you set in that variable

Comment: If I set the variable to 80, then I can access to the app only with the ip or domain name?. (e.g example.com instead of example.com:<port>). I read that when you use a URL without a port included your browser assumes it is port 80.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but yes, when I have just an app with a domain, I go to the domain and it opens the only app that is there. but haven't tested it with ip. if you set a domain, you can access to the domain without problems. you can add the principal domain to the app and will work too. with dokku domain add app_name domain.com

Comment: After dokku config:set app_name DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=80 the app restart alone but still is having the other port. Application deployed: http://<app-ip>:22445.

Comment: try with another port first to see if it work with another, in theory 80 is for nginx

Answer (score 0):

In the dashboard of digital ocean you can add the domain but you also need to ssh the app and do this:

```
dokku domains:add appName example.com
```

Now I don't have to specify the port, I can enter directly with the domain or ip (e.g. 209.107.150.99 or example.com)